# Where is physic connection from when using JNDI datasouce

Tags: jndi

When using JNDI datasouce to get connection to database.
Where does the physic connection start at?

In JNDI resource config, it includes jdbc, username ,password, even connection pool params.

My question is:
When Client system use JNDI to get a datasource and then get a connection.
Client system only get connection config params from JNDI to connect it self. or get a real connection?
If JNDI server charge the connection/pool,  Can i understand JNDI datasouce as  connection proxy?

Comment: It can be either a connection factory or just a source of configuration data, depending on how the entry you looked up was created.

Answer (score 0):

JNDI is not a proxy.
It's more like a telephone directory.

The application calls JNDI and gets back the information that tells it how to connect to the database (or whatever), then makes the connection itself.